# Working with sub-reports in asp.net rdlc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, rdlc

I have been struggling to bind subreprt in my main report where I am facing this error with no other explanation that where I am doing wrong. Tried with all the parameters setting that I found on internet but i am still not able to resolve this error.

Data retrieval failed for the subreport, 'StatusReport', located at: c:\users\prince\documents\visual studio

Here are the steps that I used to create subreport. Can anybody suggest what I have missed or where i have done wrong settings.

Steps:
1) Added an rdlc report with name "MainReport" and binded with dataset. Data set is not set to shared because my subreport will be using another & different dataset. so, I have added a table from toolbox and added dataset to bind all the "teachers" from teachers table to this main report.

2)Added another report with name "Subreport" and binded with with different dataset that will receive a param from main report. so, I have set a parameter from left pane with name "teacherId" and given its type as integer.

3)Now I went to main report and added a subreport from toolbox. Added a param with same name "teacherId" and selected a value to be provided to it.

Below is my code in MVC controller::

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            try
            {
                List<Teachers> objList = new List<Teachers>();

                using (DEVEntities entities = new DEVEntities())
                {
                    objList = entities.Teachers.ToList();

                }

                ReportViewer reportViewer = new ReportViewer
                {
                    ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local
                };
                reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath =
                    Request.MapPath(Request.ApplicationPath) +
                    @"Reports\MainReport.rdlc";

                reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new
                    ReportDataSource("TeachersSet", objList));

                reportViewer.LocalReport.SubreportProcessing += new SubreportProcessingEventHandler(LocalReport_SubreportProcessing);

                reportViewer.LocalReport.Refresh();

                ViewBag.ReportViewer = reportViewer;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            return View();
        }

         public void LocalReport_SubreportProcessing(object sender, SubreportProcessingEventArgs e)
        {
            long teachersId = Convert.ToInt64(e.Parameters[0].Values[0]);
            e.DataSources.Clear();
            List<Students_Result> objStudentList = new List<Students_Result>();
            using (DEVEntities entities = new DEVEntities())
            {
                objStudentList = entities.GetStudents(teachersId).ToList();
            }
            e.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource()
            {
                Name = "StudentsDataSet",
                Value = objStudentList
            });
        }
```

Comment: Did you verify that data is being fetched in LocalReport_SubreportProcessing event? Also, check dataset name in subreport (case etc.). Another thing - try to remove e.DataSources.Clear(); line.

Comment: Actually both the main report and subreport works fine if used individually . only when one is added as subreport to another, It causes problem and the only reason i found troublesome i that subreportprocessing event. it never gets called.